# Static Page Data - Redux or Vanilla JS?

Tags: redux

When one of my pages loads, it is handed (synchronously) a large JS object with a large amount of unnormalised data for the application to function. Some of this data is likely to be considered dynamic with certain user actions, but a lot also won't change such as application config, paths etc.

I feel like putting static data that will not change, into Redux, feels like an anti-pattern and a large overhead for a component that won't need any dynamic data from Redux? Would be better to just store all of that data in an immutable singleton instead, and only connect components that need dynamic application state?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few benefits in putting all the data in the redux store.

Selectors - are very convenient when working with a large data store, allowing components to connect to a small subtree of the store. I like [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect).

Future proofing - if in the future some if this data will need to change it will be a trivial change

Uniformity - having a single way to access the data help reduce the mental challenge of writing and debugging the code. All components behave the same, there are no special static components.

Comment: What are the performance concerns around having things connected when they only need that data once?

Comment: If the data doesn't change I don't think there will be a noticeable performance difference